# error: void value not ignored as it ought to be - C/GTK+

Tags: c++, c, gtk, gtkmm

I am trying to create a window in GTK+ that has tab looks like this:

[image]

Whenever the user clicks in the "New" button, there is a new tab appear.

However, when I was compiling my program I got an *error: void value not ignored as it ought to be*

```
phongcao@phongcao:~$ g++ /home/phongcao/C++/GTK+/newtab.cc -o /home/phongcao/C++/GTK+/newtab `pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --cflags --libs`
/home/phongcao/C++/GTK+/newtab.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/home/phongcao/C++/GTK+/newtab.cc:51:3: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
```

**And here is the code:**

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void destroy(GtkWidget *window, gpointer data) {
  gtk_main_quit();
}

void new_tab(GtkNotebook *notebook, GtkWidget *content, GtkWidget *hbox) {
  gtk_notebook_append_page(notebook, content, hbox);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
  GtkWidget *window, *label, *content;
  GtkWidget *button, *hbox, *notebook;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 10);
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "New Tab");
  gtk_widget_set_size_request(window, 300, 200);

  notebook = gtk_notebook_new();

  button = gtk_button_new_with_label("New");
  label = gtk_label_new("Tab");
  hbox = gtk_hbox_new(FALSE, 5);
  content = gtk_label_new("This is a tab");
  gint a = 0;

  gtk_box_pack_start_defaults(GTK_BOX(hbox), label);
  gtk_box_pack_start_defaults(GTK_BOX(hbox), button);

  gtk_notebook_append_page(GTK_NOTEBOOK(notebook), content, hbox);
  gtk_notebook_set_tab_pos(GTK_NOTEBOOK(notebook), GTK_POS_TOP);

  //This following line is where the error is from:
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button), "new_tab", G_CALLBACK(new_tab(GTK_NOTEBOOK(notebook), content, hbox)), NULL); 

  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(destroy), NULL);

  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), notebook);

  gtk_widget_show_all(hbox); 
  gtk_widget_show_all(window);

  gtk_main();
  return 0;
}
```

**Thanks for your help!! I really appreciate it!!**

Comment: It seems like you try to use the return value from a void function. I can't count to 53, so can't say on what line.

Comment: Can you add a comment to the line the compiler is complaining about? Your example is only 48 lines :)

Comment: I already add comment on the line that the error occurs... Sorry guys!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line number doesn't make much sense to me but I think your problem is right here (reformatted for illustrative purposes):

```
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button), "new_tab",
    G_CALLBACK(new_tab(GTK_NOTEBOOK(notebook), content, hbox)), /* <== Badness */
    NULL
);
```

You're calling the `new_tab` function inside the `G_CALLBACK` macro. The `new_tab` function returns `void` (i.e. no return value) but it is being called in a context that needs a value and hence the "void value not ignored" error. I think you mean to say something more like this:

```
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button), "new_tab", G_CALLBACK(new_tab), NULL);
```

Comment: hmm but how can I make the "New" button open a new tab if I do not pass any argument to the new_tab function... Do you know of any other way to solve this problem? Thank you ur answer is great!

Comment: You're giving `g_signal_connect` a pointer to function, it will call that function when it needs to. This `GTK_NOTEBOOK(notebook)` cast would go inside your `new_tab()` function and you can pass extra data to your function using the fourth argument to `g_signal_connect()`. The fourth argument is, AFAIK, passed to your function as the second argument, see your `destroy()` function for an example of how the callback is called. You should be able to lookup your two `GtkWidget*` when you need them rather than passing them around.

Comment: @phngcv: Your best bet would be to ask another question with details of what you tried and what went wrong. We're here to help, not write your software for you. And it is late and time for sleep where I am.

Answer (score 2):

```
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button), "new_tab", G_CALLBACK(new_tab(GTK_NOTEBOOK(notebook), content, hbox)), NULL);
```

Are you sure you want to pass parameters to `new_tab()` ? Simply  put `G_CALLBACK(new_tab)`. That will resolve error.

If you want to call "new_tab" then you have to call the function explicitly at proper place (say before passing to `G_CALLBACK`).

For your query you can refer to this [small tutorial](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/gtktutorial/gtkevents/).

Comment: hmm if I don't pass arguments to new tab then clicking the "New" button will not open a new tab.

By the way, do you know of any other way to solve this problem? (to create a window with the new button that can open new tab) I don't know if mine is already the optimal one...

Comment: You can not pass parameter to a function name when you are passing that function name as a parameter. Also, you can see that you are not doing the same for `Destroy`. Can you try removing the parameter from `new_tab` & see ?

Comment: Oh I did delete the parameters from new_tab, but when I clicked on "New" button there is no new tab appear... Do u have another solution for this new tab problem?

Comment: By the way, do u know how to pass more than 1 arguments to the g_signal_connect G_CALLBACK function? Can I add additional data to the last parameter instead of NULL?

Comment: I have put one tutorial link in the answer. Kindly refer that if it can help you.